# Nifi encrypt variables/properties files

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi [custom properties](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.2.0/building-a-dataflow/content/referencing-custom-properties-via-nifi-properties.html) (per-environment property files) looks to be a perfect way to define an environment specific paths and credentials. The only issue is how to keep sensitive information there?  There is [Nifi Encrypt-Config Tool](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#encrypt-config_tool) described in more details [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#encrypt_config_tool).

*Is [Nifi Encrypt-Config Tool](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#encrypt-config_tool) capable of encrypting variable files (defined with `nifi.variable.registry.properties`) besides `nifi.properties`?*

As far as I understood, it encrypts only `nifi.properties`. It's important, because with [Nifi Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi) I can define only `nifi.variable.registry.properties` (`NIFI_VARIABLE_REGISTRY_PROPERTIES` env var) without ability to modify `nifi.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NiFi encrypt-config tool interacts with the following configuration files:

- `nifi.properties`
- `login-identity-providers.xml`
- `authorizers.xml`
- `bootstrap.conf`
- `flow.xml.gz`

It does *not* handle any linked custom variable definition files, and there is *no* mechanism for sensitive variables to be properly secured and stored. **Variables do not support any sensitive values at all for this reason**.

Variables are treated as *deprecated* in modern versions of NiFi -- still supported but their use is discouraged -- and [*parameters*](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Parameters) were [introduced in version 1.10.0](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.10.0) as a modern solution. Parameters do support sensitive values and are accessible from every property descriptor at the framework level rather than on a per-field basis depending on the developer's explicit decision to support them. You should prioritize parameters for the storage of sensitive values needed in your flow definitions.

Depending on your threat model, you may have less robust but acceptable alternatives:

- If you accept the security level of *environment variables*, you can populate these directly and they will be referenced in any properties which support [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html), the same as "NiFi variables"
- You can edit the `nifi.properties` file through a custom Docker image, startup scripts, etc. Any modified or added properties in that file can be encrypted by adding their key (property key descriptor, not cryptographic key) as a comma-delimited list to `nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys` in that file. These properties will also be protected by the toolkit and decrypted in memory during NiFi application startup. However, `nifi.properties` is meant to hold framework-level configuration values, not component-level properties.