# NiFi Group Variables deprecation when Context Parameters lack inheritance

Tags: apache-nifi

My understanding is that Apache NiFi considers Group Variables deprecated:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003156/nifi-encrypt-variables-properties-files#:~:text=Variables%20are%20treated%20as%20deprecated,0%20as%20a%20modern%20solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003156/nifi-encrypt-variables-properties-files#:%7E:text=Variables%20are%20treated%20as%20deprecated,0%20as%20a%20modern%20solution)

> "Variables are treated as deprecated in modern versions of NiFi -- still supported but their use is discouraged"

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Variables

> "Variables and the nifi.variable.registry.properties property will be removed in a future release. As a result, it is highly recommended to switch to Parameters."

But, Parameter Contexts lack inheritance. This makes it difficult to have layered flows, and reduces the value of Process Groups, almost eliminating the convenience of nested groups outside of as in a folder storage hierarchy; placing them in groups for organization, not integration. As it stands, without Group Variables, in order to use a different set of parameters, we will have to go to every inner group and separately change its parameter context. Currently, all one has to do is edit the upper level group variables, and all contained groups follow suit as though it were one system.

Am I missing something about Parameter Contexts or configuring groups? Is there a plan for allowing inheritance on Parameter Contexts, or is the death of Group Variables greatly exaggerated?

Comment: I am finding the same frustration in that nested process groups cannot just automatically be assigned the parameter context of the parent process group. Have you found a solution or answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

NiFi Parameter context does support inheritance, from release of `Version 1.15.0`

You can check this blog that provides good details on how to achieve it.

https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/11/08/apache-nifi-1-15-0-parameter-context-inheritance

Comment: +1 but this still doesn't adress OPs problem, you will still have the same problem if you've imported a flow that has multiple nested process groups that are set to different parameter contexts that you'd like to change to the same parameter context, which is what you need to do in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue.
I have a process group that I want to duplicate. The process group has numerous nested process groups.
I don't see a simple way to edit a single parameter in the parameter context, so that process groups A and B have different values. Without having to update the parameter context in each nested process group.

I ended up doing the following:
For the process group context, set the parameter to `${ParameterName}`
Inside process group A, set the variable ParameterName to the value needed for A.
Inside process group B, set the variable ParameterName to the value needed for B.

This feels like a square peg in a round hole solution.